# Hibernate Multitenancy with different tables per tenant

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2, multi-tenant

Is there a way to define with hibernate which entities should be created in which tenant? Because for different tenant, tables are not the same.

And second question, is it possible to configure (also with hibernate) that I want to get access to tenant2 tables from tenant1.

I use embedded h2 database. I would like to automatically create tables with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto and fill these tables with flyway migration files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm using a Multitenant Architecture in Spring and I can help you with what I'm doing.

1: If you have different tables for different tenants you could either use a TenantFilter over your Entity or you can define your customized schema in schema.sql and use JdbcTemplate to execute the SQL.

I would prefer the second option over the first because it guarantees the correct schema creation.

2: You can make a switch to your tenant2 from tenant1 using a TenantContext and once you're done with your processing you can switch back to tenant1.

There are many demo projects on multitenancy with spring boot on GitHub you can have a look there.